# Overriding NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nswindow

Got a small question, i'm busy creating an OSX application. In my first view (appdelegate) i got a login screen, but after the users logged in i want (flip the logincontroller (main.xib) to remove the login screen and open a new NSWindowcontroller.

What is the best way to do that? I tried;

```
    Second = [[SecondController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"SecondController"];

[[Second window] makeFirstResponder:nil];
```

But now the second controller appears but the first controller stays. In iOS development i'm doing (want the same thing but than for OSX)

```
CategoriesViewController *tableController = [CategoriesViewController alloc];

    tableController.managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableController];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carmin is correct but you could do

`[Yourwindow close:nil];`

Answer (score 1):

Each window controller controls one window.  You have two window controllers.  You have two windows.  iOS only displays one window at a time where OSX displays multiple windows at a time.  You need to NSWindow-close the login window to make it disappear.  You may also desire to release the login window if the NSWindow-releasedWhenClosed property is not set.

Comment: But how can i close the app delegate (main.xib) `[self close]` doens't work and also `[[AppDelegate window] close];` doens't work.